# how to keep line-through on hover

Tags: css, html

How to keep `line-through` on hover?

**CODE**

```
<style>
.strike { text-decoration: line-through }
</style>

<a href="#" class="strike" >Not Applicable</a>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you elaborate more ?what is your expected result?

Comment: use javascript (JQuery maybe...), just something like `.on('hover'...`

Comment: Since the line-through doesn't go away when you hover in your code there is no way to tell what you were, in fact asking. - https://jsfiddle.net/etpgass4/

Comment: @ Paulie_D, @soorapadman Is that not clear for you as a programmer? Somebody else have the right answer without any comment. I got -1 rating for this. Who did it? and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add .`strike:hover` to the declaration

```css
.strike,
.strike:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="strike">Not Applicable</a>
```

Comment: Good answer brother. Sorry for my reputation,  I still can not give you any rating :(